IAM policy to access S3 buckets with a specific prefix
I am working on an IAM policy to restrict the access to S3 buckets with a specific prefix. S3 buckets in our account have an environment name as a prefix for example, dev-bucket1, dev-bucket2, dev-bucket3, test-bucket1, test-bucket2 and test-bucket3.
My EC2 instance in dev environment (dev and test environments are in a separate VPCs in the same account) should access only the dev buckets. I learned about s3:prefix condition but I don't have much clarity on this. By looking at the sample policies, I think s3:prefix works on only folders within the bucket. Can someone suggest a policy to access all the S3 buckets with a specific prefix?
Thanks
JR

You don't need conditions. Just write an IAM policy that allows the relevant S3 actions on the relevant S3 ARNs such as arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/someprefix/*.

It appears that your situation is:

EC2 instances that are used for Dev should only access buckets that start with dev-
EC2 instances that are used for Test should only access buckets that start with test-

You can do this by specifying a wildcard when granting access to the bucket:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:ListBucket",
            ]
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::dev-*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::dev-*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

This policy should be granted to the IAM Role that is assigned to the Dev EC2 instances.

Thanks John Rotenstein. It has resolved my issue.
